# If Registry Key Does Not Exist

Tags: c++, c, registry

I'm adding my program to start up with:

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,szPath,MAX_PATH);
HKEY newValue;
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&newValue);
RegSetValueEx(newValue,"myprogram",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)szPath,sizeof(szPath));
RegCloseKey(newValue);
return 0;
```

And I wanted to add a check if key doesn't exists only then to create it. And something else is weird with my code I have checked the registry for my key and I see in the data column my application path + "..." (after .exe) and when I double click to check the data the popup opens and it's fine it's .exe only not .exe...

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Application to Startup (Registry)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202/add-application-to-startup-registry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you wrote out is `MAX_PATH` bytes wide, regardless of how long the path really is.  Thus you probably have a lot of non-printing characters after the .exe, and that's why you see the "...".

The documentation says the last parameter is the size in *bytes* of the string, including the null terminator.  So we need to know the length of the string (`lstrlen(szPath)`), we need to account for the null terminator (`+ 1`), and we need to convert from TCHARs to bytes (`sizeof(TCHAR)*`).

```
const DWORD cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * (lstrlen(szPath) + 1);
RegSetValueEx(newValue, "myprogram", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, cbData);
```

This API is error prone, and should be used very carefully to avoid unintentional truncation or buffer overrun.  (The fact that you need those casts to get it to compile should make you very cautious.)  Many Windows functions that take pointers to strings want lengths in characters (which may not be bytes) or they figure out the length from the termination.  This one doesn't do either of those things.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't aware of that, And it did look strange here is my full code what do you think of it? Is it safe to use? http://pastebin.com/a3Bmf67H

Comment: update: It doesn't seem to work here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/aF2rdADh nothing added to registry

Answer (score 1):

you can check the registry function output....

Here I am giving the Idea you can use it...

```
bool function()
{ 
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR subKey;
    LPCTSTR subValue;
    HKEY resKey;
    DWORD dataLen;
    hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    subKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

    long key = RegOpenKeyExA(hKey, subKey, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE, &resKey);
    if(key == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
            subValue = "ProgramData";
        long key = RegQueryValueExA(resKey, subValue, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(key == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string data = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\program.exe";
            DWORD dataLen = data.size()+1;

            long key = RegSetValueExA(resKey, subValue, 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)data.c_str(), dataLen);
            if(key == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm I edited it right? New to C :) it didn't seems to work :( http://pastebin.com/QEiTKfMC and what is the right way to call it just put it inside my int main? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegCreateKeyEx()` to create a new key or open an existing key.

The "..." you see in `RegEdit` is because the column is not wide enough -- double-click at the end of the column-header to resize the column.

Comment: that's the weird thing ... shows even after I made it wider. Please can you edit my code? I'm new to C not really sure how to do that... :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest what is suggest in the MSDN: You should enumerate the Subkeys/Values in a Key with `RegEnumKey(Ex)()` or `RegEnumValue()` and then check wether the key is listed

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for an example.

Hope this helps.