# Add Application to Startup (Registry)

Tags: c++, c, windows, registry

I'm trying to add my software to registry, I have found some pieces of the codes I can use but not full working code C/C++ is new to me and can't create it on my own. But here is the basic idea: Check if reg key set if not create it.

I was able to get my program location using this code:

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,szPath,MAX_PATH);
```

And was able to create the key with: (Not sure if it's the right way)

```
HKEY newValue;
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&newValue);
RegSetValueEx(newValue,"myprogram",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)szPath,sizeof(szPath));
RegCloseKey(newValue);
return 0;
```

What is missing, A small check if the key isn't already there...

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Here's some code that likely does what you want. Call `RegisterProgram` for your EXE to self-register itself for automatically being started when the user logs in. This function calls `GetModuleFileName` and then invokes another helper function called `RegisterMyProgramForStartup` that does the writing to the registry.

Call `IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup(L"My_Program")` to detect if the registration actually exists and appears valid.

One quick note. The performance impact of checking to see if the key exists before actually writing it out again is negligible. You could just call RegisterProgram blindly and it will overwrite the key if it already exists.  Detecting if the registration exists is useful for initializing your UI checkbox that enables or disables auto-start.  (You are giving your users a choice, right?  Because I hate apps that automatically install themselves to run automatically without giving me a choice.)

```
BOOL IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup(PCWSTR pszAppName)
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LONG lResult = 0;
    BOOL fSuccess = TRUE;
    DWORD dwRegType = REG_SZ;
    wchar_t szPathToExe[MAX_PATH]  = {};
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(szPathToExe);

    lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    fSuccess = (lResult == 0);

    if (fSuccess)
    {
        lResult = RegGetValueW(hKey, NULL, pszAppName, RRF_RT_REG_SZ, &dwRegType, szPathToExe, &dwSize);
        fSuccess = (lResult == 0);
    }

    if (fSuccess)
    {
        fSuccess = (wcslen(szPathToExe) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    if (hKey != NULL)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        hKey = NULL;
    }

    return fSuccess;
}

BOOL RegisterMyProgramForStartup(PCWSTR pszAppName, PCWSTR pathToExe, PCWSTR args)
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LONG lResult = 0;
    BOOL fSuccess = TRUE;
    DWORD dwSize;

    const size_t count = MAX_PATH*2;
    wchar_t szValue[count] = {};


    wcscpy_s(szValue, count, L"\"");
    wcscat_s(szValue, count, pathToExe);
    wcscat_s(szValue, count, L"\" ");

    if (args != NULL)
    {
        // caller should make sure "args" is quoted if any single argument has a space
        // e.g. (L"-name \"Mark Voidale\"");
        wcscat_s(szValue, count, args);
    }

    lResult = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, (KEY_WRITE | KEY_READ), NULL, &hKey, NULL);

    fSuccess = (lResult == 0);

    if (fSuccess)
    {
        dwSize = (wcslen(szValue)+1)*2;
        lResult = RegSetValueExW(hKey, pszAppName, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szValue, dwSize);
        fSuccess = (lResult == 0);
    }

    if (hKey != NULL)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        hKey = NULL;
    }

    return fSuccess;
}

void RegisterProgram()
{
    wchar_t szPathToExe[MAX_PATH];

    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szPathToExe, MAX_PATH);
    RegisterMyProgramForStartup(L"My_Program", szPathToExe, L"-foobar");
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    RegisterProgram();
    IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup(L"My_Program");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you selbie it does look exactly what I needed I will test it now. One quick note: how do I add arguments to the exe. The program has config file but it doesn't always finds it so I want to add after the reg key .exe -f /includes/config.conf

Comment: I have added int main RegisterProgram(); to test if it works and I had error while compiling: 1. In function 'RegisterMyProgramForStartup':
7718:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'RegCreateKeyExA' from incompat
ible pointer type [enabled by default] 2. c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/winreg.h:66:23: note:
expected 'LPCSTR' but argument is of type 'short unsigned int *'
7725:9: warning: passing argument 2 of 'RegSetValueExA' from incompati
ble pointer type [enabled by default] 3.  expected 'LPCSTR' but argument is of type 'PCWSTR'

Comment: @MarkVoidale - You'll fix the compile issue by #defining UNICODE and _UNICODE in your build environment. I've fixed my answer above such that you don't have to do this. Also, I changed the code to add "quotes" around the exe path.  I also updated it to allow arguments passed to it as well.

Comment: many errors were fixed with the updated code just getting this now: : In function 'IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup':
:7723:23: error: expected expression before ':' token
: In function 'RegisterMyProgramForStartup':
:7749:9: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
: At top level:
:7781:10: warning: conflicting types for 'RegisterProgram' [enabled by
default]
:7051:9: note: previous implicit declaration of 'RegisterProgram' was here.This is my main: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        RegisterProgram();
        IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup(L"My_Program");

Comment: My bad. I am compiling in C++.  Fixed.

Comment: Almost! :) I'm so eager to have it working. : In function 'IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup':
:7063:56: error: 'RRF_RT_REG_SZ' undeclared (first use in this function
)
:7063:56: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for ea
ch function it appears in
: In function 'RegisterMyProgramForStartup':
: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized. Second error is at this line "wchar_t szValue[count] = {};"

Comment: I have changed 'RRF_RT_REG_SZ' to NULL and error is gone but not sure if it will effect it? Still looking into error no2

Comment: can't figure out how to fix the last error which is at wchar_t szValue[count] = {}; "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized."

Comment: @seIbie trying to fix but no luck so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940176/variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized-c

Comment: @seIbie mingw does not support wchar_t any way to fix this :(

Comment: @MarkVoidale - Change all `wchar_t` types to be WCHAR.

Comment: the world needs more people like you :D

Answer (score 4):

To check whether or not the value exists, call [`RegQueryValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx).

```
LONG retval = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "myprogram", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Note that what you called `newValue` is actually a key rather than a value. To avoid confusion you should name it such. I used the name `hKey`.

Then to check whether or not the value exists, compare `retval` against `ERROR_SUCCESS` as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx).

The other problem with your code is that there is absolutely no error checking. I'll leave that to you to address.

Comment: That's not right. You have to call `RegQueryValueEx` after you have called `RegOpenKey`. Because you need to have a handle to the key.

Comment: Still not right. `RegQueryValueEx` must be passed a key that you have opened. That's the key that `RegOpenKey` yields. You only need one key. And like I said, don't name it `newValue` because it is a key and not a value.

Comment: Should look something like this: http://pastebin.com/RaKUNUMZ  I've not checked carefully, and there's no error checking at all.

Comment: So I'm using this: http://pastebin.com/aF2rdADh and I get this error on compile In function 'main':
error: 'subValue' undeclared (first use in this function)
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for eac
h function it appears in

Comment: `subValue` has not been declared. So, declare it before trying to assign to it.

Comment: Just used subvalue manually and it worked! Will try it and see if it sets the reg key

Comment: weird but nothing added to registry :(

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging

Comment: I can't it's opensource project and can compile it only via MinGW

Comment: You can use debuggers with GCC. For example GDB. But you can also just use printf debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to write an argument about security access