# Save Me Simple Add to Startup via Registry

Tags: c++, c, registry

OK, So I have tried to do this for 2 days now. I [posted a question with my sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202) the answers just complicated everything it just didn't work. Can Some one give me a simple add to registry to startup my program?

1. It has to find the .exe file name + current path by itself.

   `(TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];`

   `GetModuleFileName(NULL,szPath,MAX_PATH);)`
2. It has to have a check if it's already exist we don't have to add it everytime...

Thank you!!

It's for Open Source C language source.

Edit: I would like to add my own custom arguments to the registry as well If possible.