# automatically run program on startup

Tags: c, windows, registry

I have written a small program which insert the value and its corresponding value into the Windows registry key.

Program is working fine but it is not inserting value and its corresponding value.

And one more thing when I run prog as an administrator RegSetValueEx() fails..but still inssert only the value not its data.

Please help for finding out the issue here.

My code is as follows..

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_DEFAULT_LIBS
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT (0x0601)
#endif  /* _WIN32_WINNT */
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include<string.h>

    BOOL InstallRunOnStartup()
    {
      HKEY key;

      long result;
      BOOL ret = FALSE;
      LPTSTR val=L"12as3d12";
        LPTSTR a=L"zzz";

      TCHAR szBuf[20];


      result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", NULL, KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_SET_VALUE , &key);
      if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
      {

        printf("hi \n");
          if (RegSetValueEx(key, a, 0, REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)val, (DWORD)(lstrlen(val)+1) == ERROR_SUCCESS)){
            printf("success \n");
            ret = TRUE;
          }
            RegCloseKey(key);
      }
      return ret;
    }




    int main()
    {
        InstallRunOnStartup();
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: There is a great answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202/add-application-to-startup-registry).

Answer (score 0):

Add your program to the following path in Windows XP:

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Can't I do this with the help of registry..??

Comment: Actually I have to write an application which needs to be started automatically as the user log on the system...

Comment: Yes you can add this using registry - but - you will have run the app at least once else how do you expect it to work - all by itself?

Comment: No. when there is an entry in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run then when system boots it automatically start that prog.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning LPBYTE(val) to a temp variable & using that?
RegSetValueEx expects the buffer in bytes & the number of bytes in that buffer.
If LPTSTR is defined as Unicode in your project, then lstrlen(val) will return the length of the string which is half the size of your byte array.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a different program and it worked..

```
HKEY hMykey; //Handle to your key
    DWORD pDWDisp; // Ignore for this
    LONG lRes; // Test Success
    char prog[] = "\"C:\\a.exe\""; //Key to launch

lRes = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
               "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\run",
               0,"Whatever",REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS ,
               NULL,&hMykey,&pDWDisp); // Open a key for edit

if(lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    MessageBox(0,"Error opening key","",MB_OK);
    return false;
    //exit(0);// Shutdown on fail
}

lRes = RegSetValueEx(hMykey,"a",0,REG_SZ,
                   (LPBYTE)prog,strlen(prog)+1);// Add your key value

if(lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    MessageBox(0,"Error saving record","",MB_OK);
    RegCloseKey(hMykey);
    return false;
    //exit(0);// Shutdown on fail
}

MessageBox(0,"Success!! Registry value recorded","",MB_OK);
RegCloseKey(hMykey);
return true;
```

Comment: There is a great answer posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202/add-application-to-startup-registry