# How to set a C++ program to start automatically when windows starts up?(By windows service solution)

Tags: c++, windows-services

I want to make my C++ program to start up automatically when the windows start up and run at the background. I searched something about it and find we can use register the C++ program to be a windows service so that when the windows start up, the program can automatically run.
So I copy this code in [Add Application to Startup (Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202/add-application-to-startup-registry) , and run the code, but I cannot see any records in my computer management->services. 
Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<Windows.h>
#include <Winbase.h>

BOOL RegisterMyProgramForStartup(PCWSTR pszAppName, PCWSTR pathToExe, PCWSTR args)
{
HKEY hKey = NULL;
LONG lResult = 0;
BOOL fSuccess = TRUE;
DWORD dwSize;

const size_t count = MAX_PATH * 2;
wchar_t szValue[count] = {};


wcscpy_s(szValue, count, L"\"");
wcscat_s(szValue, count, pathToExe);
wcscat_s(szValue, count, L"\" ");

if (args != NULL)
{
    wcscat_s(szValue, count, args);
}

lResult = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, (KEY_WRITE | KEY_READ), NULL, &hKey, NULL);

fSuccess = (lResult == 0);

if (fSuccess)
{
    dwSize = (wcslen(szValue) + 1) * 2;
    lResult = RegSetValueExW(hKey, pszAppName, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szValue, dwSize);
    fSuccess = (lResult == 0);
}
if (hKey != NULL)
{
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    hKey = NULL;
}

return fSuccess;
}

void RegisterProgram()
{
wchar_t szPathToExe[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szPathToExe, MAX_PATH);
RegisterMyProgramForStartup(L"ConsoleApplication7", szPathToExe, L"-foobar");
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
RegisterProgram();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not starting a service. You're running an application. They're not the same thing. Look for it in Task Manager on the Applications or Processes tab.

Comment: Also note that with this approach the program doesn't run when the computer starts up, it runs when the user logs on.  (And may be disabled entirely, some system administrators prefer to do so because the Run key gets abused a lot.)