# c++ Add program to startup

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, startup

I'm trying to write code which can add some software to registry. Here is my code :

```
int main()
{
    HKEY hkey;
    LONG RegOpenResult;
    const char path[] = "C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\TcpServer\\x64\\Debug\\TcpServer.exe";
    RegOpenResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
    RegSetValue(hkey,L"Server",REG_SZ, L"C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\TcpServer\\x64\\Debug\\TcpServer.exe",strlen(path)+1);
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile and run it, but it dosen't create a new key in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

I also tried what i found here:
[Add Application to Startup (Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202/add-application-to-startup-registry). But i have the same problem. I can compile and run it but no key is added.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Always check what the functions you call returns. If they fail then you need to use `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Does the program have permission to access the registry?  Did you check the return of `RegOpenKeyEx` to see if it successfully opened?

Comment: You might not have admin rights, so the attempt to set an HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry key might fail. Try running the program as administrator, or adding the key to HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead.

Comment: Besides the lack of **any** error handling, you should probably introduce yourself to the [registry redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).

Comment: I Get this :ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. So I have to run it as administrator ? Is any way to add a key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in user mode ?

Comment: No, there's no way to update HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in user mode. This is to prevent rogue programs from taking over your machine.

Comment: Your program runs in user mode (vs. kernel). If the question is whether it's possible to circumvent ACL-based security, then the answer is: "No". If the question is, whether there are other ways to install (annoying) startup applications for the current user, then you will find helpful information documented for the [Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977.aspx).

Comment: You have to be an admin in order to write to HKLM. This has been true for more than a decade, since MS started to (gently) roll out UAC in Windows XP. It started being enforced in Windows Vista. It's amazing that rules that have been in place that long have been missed by so many developers - this must be at least the 1000th post about writing to HKLM or the Windows or Windows\System32 folder and getting "access denied".

Comment: XP had no UAC. That arrived in Vista. HKLM has always required administrative rights on NT variants. Even NT 3.5.