# Master volume control in Windows, run on startup

Tags: c++, winapi

Functions like endpointvolume and waveoutSetVolume only works for the application itself, and not the entire computer. Im looking for help, at finding options for code that will:

- Control the master volume (The whole pc volume not only one application)
- When opened (exe file) the code will place it self in the startup folder on the pc. I have thought of setPathway, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to make a virus.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It does sound like that but I think it's just due to awkward phrasing.  I've answered in a way that assumes we aren't trying to make a virus, yet I think fits the questions.  I've slightly edited the question to make it sound less scary.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It's not paranoia if everyone really _is_ trying to force your whole system volume to 11 from boot ;)

Comment: yeah, now when I look back at it, it does sound like that, but its because of awkward phrasing. But dont worry, I can link the code for my program. Im just trying to make a program that turns my PC volume up to 100% or 0% (mute)  everytime i start my pc.

Comment: @Neahle: If you're running Windows, it just stays at the volume you last set it to, does it not? So put it on max and leave it there.

Comment: Well I did not know that, always thought it was on a Standard set volume, like most games. Even though I am quite sure that when I set my pc at 100 volume it will turn back to around 20, when I startup. But if thats not the case, then it seems llike I dont need to code a program to help me. Thanks both of you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SetMasterVolume()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679141(VS.85).aspx).  As for making it start every time, see here: [Add Application to Startup (Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202/add-application-to-startup-registry)